# Getting Wrong distance from the built in method distanceTo

Tags: android, google-maps, android-service, android-maps-v2, android-gps

I am try to get distance from lat log but the blow method returns wrong distance what should I do?

```
@Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    currentLatitude2 = location.getLatitude();
    currentLongitude2 = location.getLongitude();
    Location locationA = new Location("point A");
    locationA.setLatitude(currentLatitude);
    locationA.setLongitude(currentLongitude);
    Location locationB = new Location("point B");
    locationB.setLatitude(currentLatitude2);
    locationB.setLongitude(currentLongitude2);
    float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
    Toast.makeText(this, distance + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: how do you know its the wrong distance?

Comment: it returns too much distance 838345 like this i don't know what happened with this

Comment: What are the latitude and longitude of each point?

Comment: did you try taking the 2 points and mapping them on google maps to see if that is correct?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen through your this question I solved my problem thanks actually in location B I was sending wrong lat log

Comment: @tyczj  your idea was most valuable for me thanks

Comment: Thanks Stack over flow and all of you seniors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this function to get latitude and longitude first time

```
  public void getlatlong() {
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

            if (location == null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);

            } else {

                //If everything went fine lets get latitude and longitude
                currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText(this, currentLatitude + " WORKS " + currentLongitude + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        //call this function to get latitude and longitude 2nd time and this will also return you the distance 
        // Note* to check the distance you should at least cover the distance 1 or half km

         public void getlatlong2() {
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

            if (location == null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);

            } else {

                currentLatitude2 = location.getLatitude();
                currentLongitude2 = location.getLongitude();
                Location locationA = new Location("point A");
                locationA.setLatitude(currentLatitude);
                locationA.setLongitude(currentLongitude);

                Location locationB = new Location("point B");
                locationB.setLatitude(currentLatitude2);
                locationB.setLongitude(currentLongitude2);
                float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB)/1000;
               // float a = (float) (distance * 0.000621371);
                Toast.makeText(this, distance + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dist.setText(distance + "");
            }
        }
```